# How to store parameters from variadic template member function into vector?

Tags: c++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CTest
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void AddStringsToVector(const std::string &First, Args&... args);
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_stringsvec;
};

template<typename... Args>
void CTest::AddStringsToVector(const std::string &First, Args&... args)
{
    m_stringsvec.push_back(First);
    m_stringsvec.push_back(args...);

    for (auto &i : m_stringsvec)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    CTest test;
    test.AddStringsToVector("test1","test2","test3");
    system("pause");
}
```

only works when i pass two parameters:

```
test.AddStringsToVector("test1","test2");
```

If I pass any number of parameters other then two I get an error.

For example:

```
test.AddStringsToVector("test1","test2","test3");
```

> Error:
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error C2661   'std::vector>::push_back':
>   no overloaded function takes 2
>   arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursively call the function .

```
void CTest::AddStringsToVector()//function to break recursion 
{

}
template<typename... Args>
void CTest::AddStringsToVector(const std::string &First, Args&... args)
{
    m_stringsvec.push_back(First);
    AddStringsToVector(args...);


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the following be the breaking method?: `void CTest::AddStringsToVector(const std::string &First) {  m_stringsvec.push_back(First); }`

Comment: @HappyCoder The above it's equally good, will break the recursion when `Args = []`.

Answer (score 3):

A non-recursive method:

```
class CTest
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void AddStringsToVector(const std::string &first, const Args&... args)
    {
        m_stringsvec.push_back(First);
        int dummy[] = { 0, (m_stringsvec.push_back(args), 0)...}; // all magic is here
        (void) dummy; // Avoid unused variable warning.

        for (const auto &s : m_stringsvec) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_stringsvec;
};
```

The real stuff is there:

```
int dummy[] = { 0, (m_stringsvec.push_back(args), 0)...};
```

`(foo(), 0)` uses comma operator. That do the first part (the job we want) and evaluate as `0`.

With variadic expansion, it becomes `(m_stringsvec.push_back(args), 0)...`.

put the whole in initializer list to guaranty order evaluation.

In C++17, it would be even simpler with folding expression:

```
    template<typename... Args>
    void AddStringsToVector(const std::string &first, const Args&... args)
    {
        m_stringsvec.push_back(First);
         (m_stringsvec.push_back(args), ...); // Folding expression

        for (const auto &s : m_stringsvec) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Jeka: explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

Another non-recursive option (warning, brain compile):

```
struct swallow { template <typename ...T> swallow(T&& ...) noexcept { } };

class CTest
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void AddStringsToVector(const std::string &first, const Args&... args)
    {
        m_stringsvec.push_back(First);
        swallow{(m_stringsvec.push_back(args), 0)...};

        for (const auto &s : m_stringsvec) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_stringsvec;
};
```